# Read a CSV file till an empty line occurs in python and put into a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with the below mentioned format:

```
Test header
a,4955402-RX,b,m130301110
c,2839134,d,2013 03 01 12:10:53
e,,f,Pallet9
g,3.75-2,h,
i,1,j,T71
k,PASS
l,22222222222222222222222

Test Data 
Some values
```

I would like to read the header part and put the key value pair available on Header to a dictionary. Please share your thoughts on the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which columns form the key/value pairs?

Comment: key and values are present in the file in the format: key1, value1, key2, value2 and so on. Sample: key1:a, value1:4955402-RX, key2:b, value2: m130301110

Comment: So you want a list of dicts? That seems inefficient

Comment: No, I want a single dictionary with all key value pairs available on the header.

Comment: So would `c` be the third key with value `2839134`?

Comment: yes, C will be the third key with value 2839134

Comment: I would look at the `csv` module...

Answer (score 1):

Others have already talked about `csv`, so I'll go really low tech here

```
answer = {}
with open('myFile.csv') as infile:
    infile.readline()  # ignore the header line
    for line in infile:
        k1,v1,k2,v2 = line.strip().split(',')
        answer[k1] = v1
        answer[k2] = v2
```

Answer (score 0):

may you can look at: [csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: Maybe you could post an example of how OP could take advantage of `csv.DictReader`

Answer (score 0):

The standard CSV format has no representation of a "header" line. As such, your "CSV" data is going to require a custom reader, or you will have to use a standard CSV reader and process the line data yourself to deal with the header.

The [python csv reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will be extremely helpful to you in this.

Establishing the convention that a header line is of the format `HEADER, <header-name>`,

```
import csv
header = 'None'
datastore = {}
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'HEADER':
            header = row[1]
        elif:
            datastore[header] = datastore[header] or []
            datastore[header] += row
```